# Custom authorization in ASP.NET as filter or in controller's constructor?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

In my ASP.NET Web API controller, I want to restrict access to those in the User role.  The common way to do this is to extend the AuthorizeAttribute ([example](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/06/22/authorization-in-asp-net-web-api/), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211904/asp-net-web-api-authentication-and-validation)) and then sprinkle my controllers with my custom attribute (e.g. [AuthorizeUser]).

Another way to do this is to add a function in the controller's constructor.  The constructor is required anyway because I'm using dependency injection.

Here's some code:

```
public class MyController: ApiController
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IAccountUtils accountUtils;

    // Constructor
    public MyController(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
        IAccountUtils accountUtils)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.accountUtils = accountUtils;

        // Restrict access to 'User' role
        accountUtils.ThrowExceptionIfUserNotInRole(User.Identity, "User");
    }

    // More code
}
```

Because there are countless tutorial and examples of using a filter to authorize users I assumed that was the best way to go.  However, when I stepped through my code in the debugger I found that the constructor method gets fired BEFORE the filter.

To optimize code, it makes sense to break as soon as possible if the user is not authorized to access the controller.  If I'm not mistaken, then, it should be more efficient to perform authorization in the constructors instead of in a filter.  Am I correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: Throwing exceptions is not recommended for non-exceptional circumstances.  Throwing exceptions in constructors is also not recommended because it's so easy to shoot yourself in the foot with them.  Finally, this method bypasses the normal authorization pipeline, which means if you later try to do more subtle development around authorization you will be fighting it.

Comment: @MystereMan Thanks for your insightful comment.  Continuing with your thought of not bypassing the normal authorization pipeline, I can see another problem with the constructor method.  I will have difficulties using the [AllowAnonymous] attribute to make a specific action public when the rest of the controller is restricted.

Comment: I would classify that as "more subtle development around authorization"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your main concern is optimizing your code, and you're correct to note that the controller constructor runs before the authorization filter. But the difference in performance between those two solutions is *extremely* small and shouldn't really impact your service.

While throwing from a constructor might work, it's not the most elegant solution because it requires you to authorize in code rather than declaratively with an attribute. It also forces you to mix object instantiation logic with authorization logic which isn't as clean.

So I'd recommend just sticking to using an authorization filter for this one.

Comment: Great answer, Youssef!  You and Mystere convinced me that I'm not on to something amazing and should just go with the tried and true method.  Thanks!